# Initial value in Django forms

Tags: python, django, forms, model

When I try to setup initial value in Django I encounter a problem with sending that value to the database. User should not be able to change the username while posting a review. The field should be populated with username (initial value) that was given during the registration (this part works as per first screenshot) and then input rating (mandatory field) and body (optional field) should be filled by the user.
[image: Form1]

The problem is, when I press "add review" I am encountering below problem. The field 'user' gets erased, the form does not save data into the database (because the form is not valid) and does not allow to move forward until field is populated (which cannot be as the field is disable on purpose).

[image: Form2]

views.py:

```
@require_POST 
def post_review(request, bookid):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, bookid=bookid)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)
        form.fields["user"].initial = request.user.username

        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.book = book
            review.user = request.user 
            review.save()
            return redirect(review.book.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)

    return render(request, "book/review.html", {"book": book, "form": form})
```

forms.py:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["user"].initial = user
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ("user", "rating", "body")
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.TextInput(attrs={"readonly": "readonly", "disabled": "disabled"})
        }
```

I have tried shifting to different direction:

```
@require_POST
def post_review(request, bookid):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, bookid=bookid)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        initial_data = {
                "user": request.user.username
            }
        form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST, initial=initial_data)
        form.fields["user"].initial = request.user.username
        review = Review()
        if form.is_valid():
            
            review = Review(
                book=book,
                user=request.user.username,
                rating=form.cleaned_data["rating"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"]
            )
    
            review.save()
    else:
        form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)
    
    return render(request, "book/review.html", {"book": book, "form": form})
```

But this solution did not work and seems a little bit redundant. As creating model that way shouldn't be neccessary, since (as per my understanding) the form should already do that anyway.

Comment: Why do you put a `user` field in the form then? Just remove that field and use `request.user` to get the current logged in user on the server side.

Comment: I wanted the user to see who they are posting the review as, but maybe I was overthinking that idea. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Zatigem I have gone with your solution and added in HTML `Posting as {{ request.user.username }}`. It works as intended now. I was so focused on my way to solve that issue, that I didn't think of stepping back and thinking other way. Thank you once again for pointing me in the right direction.